# Create Multiple Labels in Data Template

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created a data template to use within a list view. This will later be expanded to add more content to each item in this list view. At the moment all the items that are bound to the observable collection are working as expected, except for one.
In each instance of the data template the bound properties are height, RouteName and routeStops. The height and RouteName are working fine but I'm not sure how to bind the routeStops correctly.
For each one of the RouteNames there are multiple stops, so for each data template use there must be one label that has the RouteName and multiple labels for each stop on the route (using routeStops). 
I am not entirely sure how to achieve this, I can only seem to bind one stop to one label. I want to create them dynamically to allow for any amount of stops.

So the code behind that creates the data template (Just the constructor):

```
public MainRoutePageViewDetail(MessagDatabase database)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = mainroutepageviewmodel = new MainRoutePageViewModel(database,Navigation);

        StackLayout mainstack = new StackLayout();

        var routelisttemplate = new DataTemplate(() => {

            ViewCell viewcell = new ViewCell();


            stacklayout = new StackLayout();
            stacklayout.SetBinding(StackLayout.HeightRequestProperty,"height");

            viewcell.View = stacklayout;

            // labels for template
            var nameLabel = new Label { FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold, BackgroundColor = Color.LightGray };
            nameLabel.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
            nameLabel.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;               
            nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "RouteName");
            //inforLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Stops");

            stacklayout.Children.Add(nameLabel);

            StackLayout nextstack = new StackLayout();

                var nameLabel2 = new Label { FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold, BackgroundColor = Color.Red };
                nameLabel2.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
                nameLabel2.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
                nameLabel2.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "routeStops");
                nextstack.Children.Add(nameLabel2);

            stacklayout.Children.Add(nextstack);


            return viewcell;
        });

        ListView listviewofroutes = new ListView();

        mainstack.Children.Add(listviewofroutes);


        listviewofroutes.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, "routeLabels");
        listviewofroutes.ItemTemplate = routelisttemplate;
        listviewofroutes.HasUnevenRows = true;

        Content = mainstack;

    }// end of constructor
```

This is bound to an ObservableCollection in the view model. Im going to leave this out as its irrelevant because the bindings work fine.

This calls down to functions in the model that collect data from SQL tables.

The function in the model that collects data:

```
public List<RouteInfo> getrouteInfo()
        {
            var DataBaseSelection = _connection.Query<RouteInfoTable>("Select * From [RouteInfoTable]");
            List<RouteInfo> dataList = new List<RouteInfo>();           

            for (var i = 0; i < DataBaseSelection.Count; i++)
            {

                var DataBaseSelection2 = _connection.Query<RouteStopsTable>("Select StopOnRoute From [RouteStopsTable] WHERE RouteName = ? ",DataBaseSelection[i].RouteName);

                dataList.Add(new RouteInfo
                {
                    ID = DataBaseSelection[i].ID,
                    RouteName = DataBaseSelection[i].RouteName,
                    Stops = DataBaseSelection[i].Stops,
                    DayOf = DataBaseSelection[i].DayOf,
                    IsVisible = DataBaseSelection[i].IsVisible,
                    routeStops = DataBaseSelection2[i].StopOnRoute,
                    height = 200
                });

            }
            return dataList;
        }
```

The first table (RouteInfoTable) gets RouteName and some other information and the second table gets the stops on the route using the RouteName as a key. This is all added to a list of RouteInfo instances.
DataBaseSelection2 grabs all of the stops on the route but only one of them displays. I know why this is but I dont know how to display all three.

The Table definitions and class definitions as well as the selections from the tables are not an issue. I have debugged these and they are getting the correct information I just dont know how to display it on the front end in the way I want to. Here is a visual of what I mean if its getting complicated:

[image]

The best I can do is one route stop not all three.
An ideas how to achieve this?
Sorry if its complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Grouping](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance/#Grouping) in `ListView` to achieve this visual. Basically in this case you will be defining two `DataTemplate`(s) -

1. `GroupHeaderTemplate` for `RouteName`
2. `ItemTemplate` for `StopsOnRoute`.

Comment: After considering this I have decided to take a different approach. Thanks for the answer though.